# How to get result based on column 'date' and column 'list' from 2 dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have 2 dataframe like this picture. How to create column 'Team_used' for DF_1, returns results based on NEAREST 'date' of DF_1, DF_2 and 'list_id' of DF_2.

[image]

Comment: Could you include a reproducible example of the input data you're using? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Thank you for edit my question, Nick Odell. I can but I want to ask fast by picture, because coding takes longer and I just need  the answer with a few coding suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `explode` then `merge_asof`

```
df1.date = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)
df2.date = pd.to_datetime(df2.date)
df1.sort_values('date',inplace=True)
df2.sort_values('date',inplace=True)
df2new = df2.explode('list_id_player').rename(columns = {'list_id_player' : 'id_player'})
df1 = df1.merge_asof(df2new , by = 'id_player', on = 'date', direction = 'nearest')
```